# PHP Unit test - include once error for project class

Tags: php, phpunit

I created some test but there is problem with running them

```
In bootstrap I have:

    define("BASE_PATH",str_replace("\\","/",dirname(__FILE__)));

//Get an array of your include paths
$include_parts = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR,get_include_path());

//Extend the paths
$include_parts[] = dirname(dirname(BASE_PATH)); //this is ../../

//recompile the paths and set them
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$include_parts));
/**
 * Test if phpunit running on php 5.3 or newer
 */
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '<') and exit('Test requires PHP 5.3 or newer.');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
define('DOC_ROOT','');
```

When running test I get warning

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
'/private/config/abc.php' for inclusion
(include_path='/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib/php/:.:/opt/docroot/shared:/export/home/john/public_html/sports')
in /export/home/john/public_html/sports/private/tests/Football/Match/LineupTest.php
on line 3

What is wrong because I see that included path I see my dir.

Comment: Can you paste line 3 of LineupTest.php in here please?

Comment: BTW, `exit` takes an exit code (integer). You probably want `die` here to return an error exit code and display the message.

Answer (score 2):

You are including `abc.php` using an absolute path so the include path is ignored. Do you really have `/private/config/abc.php` in your filesystem?

Comment: Yeah thats what i was thinking too (hence the comment). I'll answer anyways if you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are including `'/private/config/abc.php'` and not `'private/config/abc.php'` so the include path here doesn't matter.

That can have two causes:

- Ether you just have a typo there (hence my comment to see the line)
- or you are missing a define and your line reads `$path.'/private...` but `$path` is empty for some reason so the include is failing.